# How to change quick key for next tab in Firefox from Ctrl+PgDown to Ctrl+End

Tags: shortcut-keys, firefox, tabs

I would like to change the quick keys for switching tabs in Firefox from
`Ctrl+PgUp` and `Ctrl+PgDown` to `Ctrl+Home` and `Ctrl+End`.

I think I can do it somewhere in `about:config`, but I can't find where.

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1):

[Keyboard shortcuts - Perform common Firefox tasks quickly](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly) makes no mention of using `about:config` to change the keyboard shortcuts to move between tabs.

However, the page refers the reader to the [Saka key extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/saka-key/), which may do what you want.

The [Saka Key](https://key.saka.io/) home pages has:

> With Saka Key, your keyboard can
>
> - click links
> - scroll and zoom pages
> - switch, close, and rearrange tabs
> - and much more

(Some related extensions no longer work in Firefox 57+ which allows only web extensions.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This solves it for the bigger part. Unfortunately this doesn't work for empty tabs, I guess because they have no web content loaded, which means the Saka Key extension is also not loaded. Is this true? And does that mean that there is no way of changing this? Or are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

I am suffering from this problem too. Opened lot of tabs and hard to manage.

It doens't directly answer your question, but take this as an
alternative. Rather than switching tab one by one which is painfull.

I tried different options:

Next-browser. No, I don't want to lose ff features (but buffer list
emacs like switching is extremely cool). I've used
saka. But It's [buggy](https://github.com/lusakasa/saka/issues/8) in
firefox. Especially I find it's hard to close and move focus out ouf
saka (hitting to many ESC didn't work)

But there are lot of choices of add-ons you can use. one of them
[tab-search](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab_search/)
which works well for me.

Additionally, you can switch between the two last selected tabs back and forth  [this](https://superuser.com/questions/965060/is-there-a-way-to-switch-between-tabs-in-firefox) way. It's also select newly opened tab as 'next' choice, which is very convenient.

Update: Sunday, October  7, 2018

Now firefox had 'List all n tabs' button when we invoke 'switch-tab' using <kbd>Ctrl-TAB</kbd>. This button shows up when tab reach n minimum number (approx 25). So I will use this instead additional add-ons.